# How to filter nonmatching array elements with BASH expansion?

Tags: bash

How do I remove every item that does not have the matching prefix, i.e. negate the following pattern:

```
array=(elem1:a elem1:b elem2:a elem2:b)
prefix=elem1:
echo ${array[@]//$prefix/}
```

So that the new array will only have elements that matched the prefix `(elem1:a elem1:b)`

There are others questions that seem similar, such as [Bash: How to select elements in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47801772/bash-how-to-select-elements-in-array) or search and replace on string questions but I can not find one that answers this question.

Comment: Doesn't randomir's answer to [the question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47801772/bash-how-to-select-elements-in-array) do that (although you have to remove the `/` from the test, because you don't have `/` after the prefix)? BTW, the substitution you have won't work right for several reasons.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, *“remove every item that does not have the matching prefix”* does not *negate* your code snippet in any way or sense.

Assuming that you want to remove array items with a certain prefix, here’s an option:

```sh
array=(elem1:a elem1:b elem2:a elem2:b)
prefix=elem1:

for index in "${!array[@]}"; do
  [[ "${array[index]}" == "${prefix}"* ]] && unset 'array[index]'
done

echo "${array[@]}"   # It contains the expected items, but...
echo "${!array[@]}"  # ...the indices are now sparse.

dense_array=("${array[@]}")  # This could do.

for var_name in {,dense_}array; do
  declare -n some_array="${var_name}"
  for index in "${!some_array[@]}"; do
    echo "${var_name}[${index}]='${some_array[index]}'"
  done
done
```